# Video inside android app

Tags: android

I would like to add one video to the main screen of my application but I want to user to be able to do other things in the app meanwhile. Think about some video animation or flash movie for some website that you can watch the video and look on other things in the website.

lets say I have buttons and more things in the same screen and I want a small video to be playing there too in a loop.

is this possible?

I thought that Flash movie could be good for that, but its only for latest versions of android then I don't want to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: so the user will always stay on the main screen while the video is playing? or will he move to other subscreens while the video plays back on the main screen in the background?

Comment: He'll move to other screens while the video was playing. But let's say I want to play the video once without a loop.. its still the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html).